# How to sum bigints in sql-server, while ignoring arithmetic overflow error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am running `select sum(x) from y`, where `x` is of type `bigint`, and contains 64-bit numbers.

Sql-server throws `Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type bigint`.

I am fine with just ignoring the overflow, the way C would. I only need the lower 64-bits of the result.

If I was trying to sum ints, I could convert them to bigint and then the sum would complete in every practical query. But what do I do when I want to sum bigints?

Comment: `CAST` the value to a `decimal(38,0)` first, then `SUM`. If you then want to dispose of values too large, `TRY_CAST` it back to a `bigint`.

Comment: `TRY_CAST` will return `NULL` if the value exceeds max bigint. Probably you would need to do something with modulus to simulate it overflowing C style

Comment: @DhruvJoshi If you (re)read the question I think you'll find that it isn't a duplicate.